# How to restrict movement of textbox outside the canvas ?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have added a textbox with adorners in Canvas and I don't want to move outside of the canvas. What  do I have to do? I am moving at runtime the textbox.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684904/how-can-i-get-wpfs-cliptobounds-to-work

Comment: Almost no container constrains its children position

Comment: How did you write your adorners? They're what's handing the moving of the textbox, so they're where you would need to add the constraints.

Comment: MSin adorner layer added the thumbs , did you tried to add textbox in MS Paint move upto end what will happen ,it will restrict in my case it will allow to move and resize